# RecycleView leaves empty space at the bottom because of toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, stickyrecycleview

**Update:**

- *Actual issue is with `CoordinatorLayout` not with `RecycleView`.*
- *Instead of using `RecycleView` I tried `TextView` inside `ScrollView` and it is the same issue.*
- *Something is not aligned if you have `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` and using `CoordinatorLayout` with another `ToolBar` as Sticky Header with scrolling element at bottom*

**Original:**

I'm in process of develop a view which needed Sticky header implementation with recycle view at bottom. I have used [Coordinator layout support](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout_scrollflags/) as describe here.

What is working:

- Sticky View on scroll list.

  - Toolbar using **`layout_collapseMode = pin`** & `CollapsingToolbarLayout` using **`layout_scrollFlags = scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap`** property.
  - Recycle view with behaviour **`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`"**

What is issue:

- Recycle view leaving margin at bottom, it has same size as `Toolbar` I'm using to sticky view.
- Recycle view last item does not display, it need extra **`bottom_margin`** as size of sticky tool bar view.

**Observation:**

- If I fill recycle instant then it work. But if notify it with some delay then it causing issue.
- **Update.** In another trial and run**, instead of using Recycle I put an `TextView` inside the `NestedScrollView`.(PFA) (not updated in layout here)

  - Here I have added text from xml and after delay of 2 second just append some more text and it's same result.
  - It's layout that take bottom margin again. So nothing specific related to Recycle view, it seems some issue with `CoordinatorLayout`.

I have tried with multiple solution available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33940835/2624806), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34217974/2624806), but none of working.

PFA, current output.

[image]

**Update** PFA, experiment with text view with delay.

[image]

Here is the layout file.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/summaryAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:background="@drawable/fable_1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3" />

            <!-- This is sticky header-->
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/summaryToolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_layout_margin"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:text="Name" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:text="Offer"/>

                </FrameLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <!-- Bottom margin if I do't use then it does not display last child item. Wired but true in this case-->

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: had you added : android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  to your coordinator view?

Comment: yes, but that pushing layout up and resulting action bar cut from top.

Comment: Don't you have `android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"` set?

Comment: @PFuster so I added issue in What is issue section. Removing of that even not fixing bottom space issue. Please also refer **Observation** section, that's where I could be able to conclude so far.

Comment: @CoDe: Did you find a solution for this issue? I also have an ugly white bar appearing at the bottom of my RecyclerView when I'm scrolling upwards. It makes my NavBar intransparent. "clipToPadding=false" has no effect. See here the video: https://github.com/patrickfrei/test_coding/blob/main/issue.webm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try the below layout file. I have tested it and it works fine. You can remove the marginButtom from the recyclerview as well.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/summaryAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:background="@drawable/fable_1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3" />

        <!-- This is sticky header-->
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/summaryToolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="@dimen/common_layout_margin"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Name" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:text="Offer"/>

            </FrameLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Adding a relative layout as Parent layout fixed this great issue. Thank you Jiten.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the `CoordinatorLayout` (maybe the `AppBarLayout` or `CollapsingToolbarLayout` - not sure which component) is recording the incorrect height of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` due to the sticky toolbar. The behavior differs if items are added before or after the initial layout.

Try the following:

1. Remove `android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"` from the XML for the `RecyclerView`.
2. Add `android:minHeight="72dp"` to the XML for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Since your sticky toolbar is set at `72dp`, it is OK to use `minHeight` set to `72dp`.

If you have trouble with this, post back here.

---

Here is a quick demo of your layout using a `NestedScrollView` and the changes mentioned above.

**Update:** I have worked this out using `RecyclerView` which displays the same problem. Demo project showing the problem and the fix is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Cheticamp/BottomSpace).

[image]

Here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  
    // Set to true to break the layout; false for it to work.  
    // The setting of this flag should only matter for the 
    // layout activity_not_working.  
    private boolean mBreakIt = true;  

    //    private int mLayoutToUse = R.layout.activity_not_working;  
    private int mLayoutToUse = R.layout.activity_working;  

    private LinearLayout mLayout;  

    @Override  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(mLayoutToUse);  

        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);  
        if (mBreakIt) {  
            mLayout.post(new Runnable() {  
                @Override  
  public void run() {  
                    addViews();  
                }  
            });  
        } else {  
            addViews();  
        }  
    }  

    private void addViews() {  
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {  
            TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);  
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
            tv.setText("TextView #" + (i + 1));  
            mLayout.addView(tv);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

**activity_working.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/summaryAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="72dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:background="@drawable/beach"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3" />

            <!-- This is sticky header-->
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/summaryToolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_layout_margin"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:text="Offer"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Bottom margin if I do't use then it does not display last child item. Wired but true in this case-->
    <!-- Removed following: -->
    <!--android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"-->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_not_working.xml**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/summaryAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:background="@drawable/beach"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3" />

            <!-- This is sticky header-->
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/summaryToolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="@dimen/common_layout_margin"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:text="Offer"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Bottom margin if I do't use then it does not display last child item. Wired but true in this case-->
    <!-- Removed following: -->
    <!--android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"-->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A TextView" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but in my case it is same issue. Please note I already have toolbar set as an Action Bar. I'm still on it and will update soon.

Answer (score 4):

The `RecyclerView` height is just being calculated wrongfully, when entering scroll. these two different examples only added confusion to the question, without the least `Java` code provided.

simply remove this one line from the `RecyclerView`:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
```

this attribute has little use, because it's the default value:

```
android:visibility="visible"
```

don't set the `RecyclerView` height like this:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

but make it fill up the available space:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1.00"
```

so that the `RecyclerView` would always fit, in case there is a toolbar present, whether or not - this toolbar just shouldn't be set sticky, because this is what demands halfheartedly "fixing" the layout. a [BottomNavigationView](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) might eventually be useful there, depending on what that toolbar, might be good for. even found the source of the script: [CoordinatorBehaviorExample](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample), which should have been attributed, as the license requires it.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have added comment in layout section. About weight property, it will not be possible as direct child of **CoordinatorLayout**, though putting NestedScrollView and take RecycleView inside LinearLayout also not making any difference.

Comment: Toolbar I'm using as an part of Sticky header, in GIF I have shown with text (Name & Offer label). About BottomNavigationView, not really sure how this can fix it !!

Answer (score 3):

I assume there could be issue while adding new data and notify adapter.

You should change from `notifyDataSetChanged()` to `notifyItemInserted(index)`.

More documentation on `notifyItemInserted(index)` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hiren, this help to fix issue till some extend but original issue still persist. Please refer updated post.

Answer (score 3):

Hey you have set a `marginBottom` attribute there. Remove that. That's where the error is. The code for the `RecyclerView` should be:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:listItem="@layout/item_dessert" />
```

Comment: Hi Gourav, it is needed for some weird unknown reason, issue I have added in **What is issue section** and in layout section comment as well. Please refer.

Comment: android:clipToPadding="false" is what I was looking for... +1